# Running a Servlet with Eclipse Java EE

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to run a servlet using Apache Tomcat v7.0 (i also tried 8) using Dynamic web module version 3.0.

[image: Code]

I've also tried with the xml file (even though it should work without it because its 3.0) and it doesn't work aswell... What the hell am I doing wrong?

The error is The requested resource is not available.

EDIT: Ok, so I made a XML file again so you can maybe tell me what i'm doing wrong in it...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>code.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

code is the name of the package inside src.

I'm using the url: http://localhost:8080/hello , still not working

Comment: I'm not sure but, shouldn't be defined in the web.xml which URL patterns the servlet can receive??

Comment: what url u have used?

Comment: I edited the question with the URL and XML file

Comment: @Rayden please try `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*")`. If this works I'll put it up as an answer with a detailed explanation about why it works. You shouldn't need web.xml with this configuration.

Comment: So this is kinda sad, but i restarted eclipse and now it works with the code I posted, but your way works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite unclear from the question, either you want to create `Servlet` using `@WebServlet` or through `web.xml`.

To create `Servlet` using `@WebServlet` you do not need `web.xml` configuration at all.

Just create a class annotated with `@WebServlet` and call the url as below:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Then call url: `http://host:port/context-root[/url-pattern]`, for me it's `http://localhost:8989/TestApplication/HelloServlet`

Or if you want to create through `web.xml` then load the servlet on startup as below:

```
<servlet>
        <display-name>Hello Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.package.name.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Again you can call like : `http://host:port/context-root[/url-pattern]`, for me it's `http://localhost:8989/TestApplication/HelloServlet`

Comment: I didn't understand how to get the application context name.

Comment: In Eclipse, Right Click your project, then go to `Web Project Settings`, there you will see `Context root`

Answer (score 1):

The package is wrong, you defined in the web.xml:

```
  <servlet-class>code.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
```

and in the class

```
package net.codejava;
```

So this should fix the problem:

```
<servlet-class>net.codejava.HelloServlet</servlet-class
```